# String Concatenation + Replace

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to remove accentes, spaces and special characters in Oracle SQL.
(I thought about using *pipe* and *replace*)

**My code so far:**

```
SELECT NR_CONHEC || ' - ' || RAZAO_SOCIAL_TRANSP FROM geq_gl_ctms_frete
```

**For example:**

```
7590 - J. T. TRANSPORTES LTDA. - ME
```

**Needed output:**

```
7590-JTTRANSPORTESLTDA-ME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
SELECT  NR_CONHEC||'-'|| reexp_replace(regexp_replace(RAZAO_SOCIAL_TRANSP 
RAZAO_SOCIAL_TRANSP,'.',''),' ','') FROM geq_gl_ctms_frete;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 select regexp_replace('7590 - J. T. TRANSPORTES LTDA. - ME','[[:space:]]|\.')
        as "Result String"
   from dual;

 Result String
-------------------------
7590-JTTRANSPORTESLTDA-ME
```

For your case, replace with the following query :

```
SELECT regexp_replace( NR_CONHEC || ' - ' || RAZAO_SOCIAL_TRANSP,'[[:space:]]|\.') 
  FROM geq_gl_ctms_frete;
```

and if you want to remove more special chars. and accentes other than dot, add whichever you want after `|\.` such as `|\%|\&|\è...`, then those characters `%`, `&` or `è` are removed from the string.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '7590 - J. T. TRANSPORTES LTDA. - ME' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '[^([:alpha:][:digit:]-)]') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-------------------------
7590-JTTRANSPORTESLTDA-ME

SQL>
```

I.e. replace anything that isn't a letter, a number or a hyphen with *nothing*.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select regexp_replace (NR_CONHEC|| ' - ' || RAZAO_SOCIAL_TRANSP, '[^-0-9a-zA-Z]') as rez  from geq_gl_ctms_frete ;
```